# Choosing the appropriate Role for a Marketing Cloud user

Tags: marketing-cloud

When I consult the Marketing Cloud documentation on Roles and Permissions I am not clear on the most appropriate Role to assign to a User.

For example, let's say you want to give a Junior Marketing User permission to:

- Create and edit Content (Email, SMS and Cloud Pages)
- Create and edit Data extensions
- Create and edit Advertising Studio audiences
- Create, edit and run Activities & Automations
- Create, edit and run Journey Builder Journeys
- Create and Run all Reports

You don't want them to:

- Access the Marketing Cloud Setup Menu
- Access Email Studio Administration
- Access Advertising Studio Administration
- Access Mobile Connect Administration
- Be able to export data in any way

What would be the appropriate Roles for this User? Would they also need individual permissions applied?

Next example, let's say you want to give a Senior Marketing User permission to:

- Create, edit and Delete Content (Email, SMS and Cloud Pages)
- Create, edit and Delete Data extensions
- Create, edit and Delete Advertising Studio audiences
- Create, edit, Delete and run Activities & Automations
- Create, edit, delete and run Journey Builder Journeys
- Create and Run all Reports
- Access the Marketing Cloud Setup Menu
- Access Email Studio Administration
- Access Advertising Studio Administration
- Access Mobile Connect Administration

What would be the appropriate Roles for this User? Would they also need individual permissions applied?

Is there more information available somewhere or are the below links the only documentation?

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_roles.htm&type=5

Kind Regards

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom roles and assign the required level of permissions to those roles. In that case, you need not provide individual permissions to the users.
You can find this option here:

Go to Email Studio-> Admin-> Account Settings-> Roles

Under Roles, you will see a create button. Provide all the required permissions for a Junior Marketing user to it and save it as Junior Marketing User (for example). You can then assign this role to every Junior Marketing user.

If you don't see this option, you can ask Salesforce Support to enable that for you. You need to have System Admin to create the roles. Snapshot attached for better understanding of how I have allowed this user to access Content and Subscribers but denied him access to Admin:
[image]